Name the movie where brother & sister fall in love with each other?
Can anyone help me identify this movie?
Language: English
Country: US
Year: Not sure (But definitely not an old movie. Not the 80s)
Genre: Drama/Romantic
Actress: A blonde girl in her twenties. She's hot.
I remember this newspaper ad for this movie. I was a kid at that time. I think I saw this ad maybe in the year 2003 or 2002 or 2001. This movie was getting featured in star Movies that night at 9 p.m show.
I read the synopsis.
Here's what I remember:
One among the hero or heroine is trying to find his/her family history or trying to find out his/her parents using the help from the other one. They eventually fall in love with each other. Initially they are not aware of the fact that they have blood relationship. Hero is heroine brother, but they didn't knew this fact because of some circumstances. Finally, they know this mess & are confused on what to do next.
I never saw this movie. I read the synopsis. I am sure this movie was released after 1997.

This reminds me of a spanish movie "Lovers of the Arctic Circle" released in 1998.

No. This ain't the movie. The movie I am looking for is definitely an American movie. The lead actress is a blonde & much younger than the one in 'Lovers of the Arctic Circle'. @chaitanya89

Possibly Say It Isn't So from 2001 with Heather Graham. From IMDb:

Young orphan Gilly (Klein) finds out his lover Jo (Graham) may actually be his biological sister. After they break up he discovers he's not related and travels across the country to stop her impending wedding. Unfortunately the entire nation has heard the same story and thinks he's just after incestuous thrills. 

Here's the trailer:



